# Vertica query returns empty result set at SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, vertica, vsql

We are creating SSRS reports using Vertica Data Source.  Vertica query does not return any result set when we using Temp tables on it. Pleas find below sample query,

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Employee;
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee(EmpNo INTEGER, EmpName VARCHAR) ON COMMIT preserve rows unsegmented ALL nodes;
INSERT INTO Employee (EmpNo, EmpName) VALUES (1000, 'AAA');
INSERT INTO Employee (EmpNo, EmpName) VALUES (1001, 'BBB');
SELECT EmpNo, EmpName FROM Employee;
```

Please advise how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please try qualifying your schema (i.e. `public`).

Comment: Kermi, I already have tried with my schema and public schema and I tried with Global Temp table also. Not working all cases.